# Kotlin : Optional Dependency Injection Using Spring

Tags: spring, kotlin, dependency-injection

What is the kotlin alternative for

```
@Autowired(required=false)
private DependencyC dependencyC;
```

and

```
private Optional<HelloService> optionalHelloService;
public HelloController(Optional<HelloService> helloService) {
    this.optionalHelloService = helloService;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work about it ? Why do you think that there is a fundamental difference between java and kotkin for dependency injection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make that property nullable then:

```
class HelloController(
    @Autowired(required = false) val helloService: HelloService?
)
```

Comment: I am trying this with a list of beans, but it's not working. Any idea? `@Autowired(required = false) val requestHandlingServices: List<RequestHandlingService>?`

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is outdated. Spring uses the type information to infer whether a bean is optional. See
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/languages.html#kotlin-annotations, specifically

> In a similar fashion, Spring bean injection with @Autowired, @Bean, or @Inject uses this information to determine if a bean is required or not.

Because `@Autowired` is optional for constructor parameters, the shortest Kotlin alternative is

```
class HelloController(private val optionalHelloService: HelloService?)
```

Comment: This has been possible since the first release of Kotlin support in Spring Framework 5.0.0